# C++ Calling a non-const operator overload with two const arguments

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've overloaded the `operator-` (and `-=`) for 2D vectors (and scalars):

```
Vector2D Vector2D::operator-(const Vector2D& rhs) {
    return Vector2D(this->GetX() - rhs.GetX(), this->GetY() - rhs.GetY());
}
```

In order to get this call to not complain that `no operator '-' matches these arguments` I had to do this:

```
a2de::Vector2D Vector2D::GetFacingVector(const Vector2D& target, const Vector2D& source) {
    a2de::Vector2D facingVec(const_cast<Vector2D&>(target) - const_cast<Vector2D&>(source));
    return facingVec;
}
```

Or this:

```
a2de::Vector2D Vector2D::GetFacingVector(const Vector2D& target, const Vector2D& source) {
    a2de::Vector2D facingVec(Vector2D(target) - Vector2D(source));
    return facingVec;
}
```

Both of which seem like a very bad thing to do. (Not-with-standing the phrase "only use `const_cast` when you know what you're doing because the compiler will assume you do!")

Are these correct or is there a better way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: I have never, ever needed to use `const_cast` for anything

Comment: @Aesthete You must not have read `Effective C++ 3rd. Edition` yet. Quite a good read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operator should be:

```
Vector2D Vector2D::operator-(const Vector2D& rhs) const
```

Note the **const**.

Comment: Someone downvoted my answer.  Apparently it's not helpful.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Your `operator-` should be declared as a `const` member function, meaning it promises not to change `*this`:

```
Vector2D Vector2D::operator-(const Vector2D& rhs) const {
    return Vector2D(this->GetX() - rhs.GetX(), this->GetY() - rhs.GetY());
}
```

Or better still, make it a non-member, so that implicit conversions can happen on both sides of a minus sign, not just the right side:

```
inline Vector2D operator-(const Vector2D& lhs, const Vector2D& rhs) {
    Vector2D result(lhs);
    result -= rhs;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to use `const`. Here are some that may fix your problem

```
Vector2D Vector2D::operator-(const Vector2D& rhs) const
{
    return Vector2D(this->GetX() - rhs.GetX(), this->GetY() - rhs.GetY());
}
```

Notice the `const` at the end of your method? This signifies that the method is guaranteed **not to change any member variable** during it's scope.

Answer (score 1):

Try mark operator- as const member function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd better try to not write the words that spring to mind. Suffice it to say, they would cause extreme downvoting of this answer, and maybe even drag in the Reddit crowd. Anyways, your member function is not `const`, so it must be called on non-`const` argument.

Here's direct technical fix:

```
Vector2D Vector2D::operator-(const Vector2D& rhs) const
{
    return Vector2D(this->GetX() - rhs.GetX(), this->GetY() - rhs.GetY());
}
```

Here's a better way, with the operator as a free-standing function:

```
Vector2D operator-( Vector2D const& a, Vector2D const& b)
{
    return Vector2D( a.GetX() - b.GetX(), a.GetY() - b.GetY() );
}
```

Finally, think about naming. Do you ever write `getSin( angle )`? No?

```
Vector2D operator-( Vector2D const& a, Vector2D const& b)
{
    return Vector2D( a.x() - b.x(), a.y() - b.y() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to make operator a nonmember function.  This way you don't run into your problem.  Also, both arguments could be converted to Vector2D if you have constructors to do that.

```
class Vector2D
{
...
    Vector2D& operator-=(const Vector2D& rhs)
    {
      this->x -= rhs.GetX();
      this->y -= rhs.GetY();
      return *this;
    }
...
};

Vector2D Vector2D::operator-(const Vector2D& lhs, const Vector2D& rhs)
{
  Vector2D temp(lhs);
  return temp -= rhs;
}
```

Most non-modifying arithmetic operators in the standard are non-member symmetric like this.